# asp.net membership: password WITHOUT non-alpha character

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, passwords

I'm using the configuration manager to create a user for the application and when it comes to the password file, I'm forced to choose a password that has a non-alphabetical character like

```
MyPassword:1
```

I want to be able to create a password that doesn't have this requirement.

Is a switch to toggle somewhere?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have 2 attributes in the [SqlMembershipProvider Configuration Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx#paght000022_sqlmembershipproviderconfig), called

`minRequiredPassword` (you didn't ask for this, but it's good to know)

> Specifies the minimum number of characters required in a password. The value can be from 1 to 128.

and `minRequiredNonAlpha`

> Specifies the minimum number of non-alphanumeric characters required in a password. This configuration attribute cannot be set to a value greater than the value of the `minRequiredPasswordLength`. This means the configuration setting must be in the range of 
>   `minRequiredPasswordLength`, inclusive of `minRequiredPasswordLength`.

So all you need to do is use:

`minRequiredNonAlpha="0"`

like:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" 
       protection="All" 
       timeout="30" 
       name="AppNameCookie" 
       path="/FormsAuth" 
       requireSSL="false" 
       slidingExpiration="true" 
       defaultUrl="default.aspx"

       minRequiredNonAlpha="0"
       minRequiredPassword="6"

       cookieless="UseCookies"
       enableCrossAppRedirects="false"/>
</authentication>
```

Comment: Problem: it says "minRequiredNonAlpha attribute is not allowed!

Comment: minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"  not minRequiredNonAlpha="0"